# Visual studio automatically puts plus sign when I hit enter inside a string. How can I disable it?

Tags: visual-studio

It wasn't like this before. I reinstalled it after formatting my pc.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BddK5.png)

Comment: I would imagine it's doing this because putting a carriage return inside the string itself is invalid syntax.  If you want to include a carriage return in the string literal itself then you're probably looking for [verbatim strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this a long time too. I finally found it here:

- Click Tools -> Options
- Go to Text Editor/C#/Advanced
- Uncheck "Split string literals on enter"

This will prevent Visual Studio from inserting a plus-character when you try to press Enter inside a string.